# Set custom UIAccessibility on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, uiaccessibility

I'm programatically setting accessibility on all my UITabBarItem's (label, value & hint) but when I test the accessibility - it correctly see's the tab, however it's relaying the system default (not what I have set in my accessibility properties).

The system default text is almost perfect, however I (purposely) have no title on the tabs (**UITabBarItem.title** is blank), so it doesn't read out the tab name that I try and set in the **accessibilityLabel** or **accessibilityValue**

I'm happy for the default to tell me the position and number of tabs, but I just want it to relay the selected tab's name (e.g. "Home")

Any pointers with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?